# Old plain way to remove selected elements from HTML

Tags: javascript, html

this is my own website https://celestialbunny.github.io/frontend_02/ I am trying to do some "dumping" - removing certain elements from the page via plain javascript.

I have tried:

```
let body = document.body
let navs = document.querySelectorAll('nav');
let headers = document.querySelectorAll('header');
let footers = document.querySelectorAll('footer');
let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
let as = document.querySelectorAll('a');
let links = document.querySelectorAll('link');
let scripts = document.querySelectorAll('script');

body.remove(navs);
body.remove(headers);
body.remove(footers);
body.remove(imgs);
body.remove(as);
body.remove(links);
body.remove(scripts);
```

Here's the case, let's just say that I did only:

1. `let body = document.body;`
2. `let navs = document.querySelectorAll('nav');`
3. `body.remove(navs)`
   This will result in the deletion for the whole page.

I have tried to refer to documentation on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/remove and I can't seem to understand why deleting "child" from "body" will result in a "blank page"

How can I remove the particular element without affecting the rest?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is not right. You don't need body.

example for img:

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
[...imgs].forEach(e => e.remove());
```

If you select HTML-Elements with `document.querySelectorAll()` you get a NodeList back. A NodeList is similar to an array but you can't loop it directly.

To delete the target elements in the NodeList you have to loop throug the List.

With `[...imgs]` or with `Array.from(imgs)` you convert the NodeList to an Array. 
Now you can loop through the array and remove its members.

Comment: Thank you @d-h-e, I have refined it into what I need and get it to run:
    `const deletes = [
        'nav',
        'header',
        'footer',
        'img',
        'a',
        'link',
        'script'
    ];
    
    for (i in deletes) {
        const item = document.querySelectorAll(deletes[i]);
        [...item].forEach(e => e.remove())
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You pass in the index into the remove function.

let's take navs here:

`let navs = document.querySelectorAll('nav');`

then you have a query selection list, an array of nav's

Assuming the array is not empty, you then select one of the items to remove from the DOM:

`navs.remove(0)`

that will remove the first item in the navs list.

Answer (score 0):

The link that you gave says `.remove()` is used to remove an element from collection and it takes the index of element to remove as a parameter. So to remove all navs from your body you will have to loop through navs and remove them.

```js
let navs = document.querySelectorAll('nav');
[...navs].forEach(n => n.remove());
```

```html
<nav>Test</nav>
<nav>Test2</nav>
<div>Test3</div>
```